# How can I set column types of several columns in empty R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, types

I'm trying to create an empty dataframe with specific columns names and columns types. What I have is a function that receives a list with this structure:

```
list$
    $name_1$
           $class
           $more_stuff
    $name_2$
           $class
           $more_stuff
    ...
```

So, I create an empty dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(names(my_list)), nrow = 0))
colnames(df) <- names(my_list)
# set column types
```

Every item of the list has a 'class' atribute which contains the data type. These can be: "character", "numeric", "datetime", "boolean", and they must be converted into:

```
"character" -> character
"numeric"   -> numeric
"datetime"  -> datetime<UTC>
"boolean"   -> character
```

Because this dataframe will be joined into another one that has these columns.

I tried something like this, but the datetime column was incorrect:

```
  for (i in c(1:length(my_list))) {
    cast_function = switch(my_list[[i]]$class,
                           'character' = as.character,
                           'numeric'   = as.numeric,
                           'datetime'  = as.POSIXct,
                           'boolean'   = as.character)

    empty_df[[i]] <- cast_function(empty_df[[i]])
  }
```

How could I perform this operation? Is there any better way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What about `data.frame(x = character(), y = numeric(), z = integer())`?

Comment: I thought that, but the problem is that the list could have any number of items (>= 1), so I need a more flexible solution. I don't know if there is a R-equivalent for Python's *list and how could I use it for this problem

Comment: Do you know `do.call()`? You can use it to construct a function call.

Comment: No, I don't know it. Is it like the Python's "splat" operator? How could it be applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this snippet contains all the elements you might need:

```r
lst <- list(
  x = list("character", letters[1:5]),
  y = list("numeric", as.double(1:5)),
  w = list("boolean", as.character(as.integer(c(
    T, F, F
  )))),
  z = list("datetime", Sys.time())
)

my_classes <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) x[1]))

mapping <- list(
  character = character(),
  numeric = numeric(),
  datetime = structure(double(), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
  boolean = character()
)

do.call(tibble::tibble, args = mapping[my_classes])
#> # A tibble: 0 × 4
#> # … with 4 variables: character <chr>, numeric <dbl>, boolean <chr>,
#> #   datetime <dttm>
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, but the "do.call" throws an error when there are more than one element per type, because it receives 2 arguments named "character"

Answer (score 0):

Following plant's answer, I could get this solution:

```
my_list <- list(
  name_1   = list( class = "character", stuff = 11 ),
  name_2   = list( class = "boolean", stuff = 22 ),
  name_3   = list( class = "numeric", stuff = 22 ),
  name_rr  = list( class = "character", stuff = 54 ),
  name_56  = list( class = "datetime", stuff = 89 ),
  name_zzz = list( class = "boolean", stuff = 134 )
)


my_classes <- list()
for (i in my_list) {
  my_classes <- c(my_classes, i$class)
}

mapping <- list(
  character = character(),
  numeric = numeric(),
  datetime = structure(double(), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
  boolean = character()
)

my_args <- mapping[unlist(my_classes)]

names(my_args) <- names(my_list)

do.call(tibble::tibble, args = my_args)

# my_function(my_list_1)
# A tibble: 0 x 6
# ... with 6 variables: character <chr>, boolean <chr>, numeric <dbl>, character <chr>, datetime <dttm>, boolean <chr>
```